# How to checkout configuration file and rename it using mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

How do I tell mercurial to copy a file from /home/configs/config.ini into my local clone everytime I run hg clone /home/hg/repo1 without tracking it ?

For example

```
> ls -l /home/hg/repo1
  file_one.py
  file_two.py

> hg clone /home/hg/repo1 /home/me/repo1
> cd /home/me/repo1
> ls -l /home/me/repo1
  file_one.py
  file_two.py
  config.ini
```

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way of doing this is by tracking a file called, say, `config.ini.example`, and then copying it to `config.ini`, and include `config.ini` in your `.hgignore` file. You could also make your application generate a `config.ini` when it is first run if it does not yet exist.

There are no (documented) hooks for the cloning action because when you clone, you create a new repository. Because this repo is brand new, it has no `.hgrc` file in order to define hooks. That is, the hooks you run are the ones from the *new* repository, not the *old* one.

Comment: Hi Paul. This is exactly what I would like to do - copying the config.ini file from /home/configs/config.ini - but on clone directly - without having to do a manual cp. I was looking into hooks, but I can't find a hook for a cloning action.

Comment: So what is your suggestion Paul ? I would prefer to avoid manually copying stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a hook, but you're going to find it more trouble than just creating a clear README.txt. :)

The hook would look like:

```
[hooks]
post-clone = cp -i config.ini.sample config.ini
```

As Paul Fischer pointed out, it's better to use a `.sample` that's in the repo than something like `/home/configs/config.ini` that's out of the repo.

The problem, as VonC points out, is that hooks aren't copied down on clone -- and for good reason: if cloning brought down hooks too then I'd put `post-clone = rm -rf ~` in there are really ruin your day.

So if you're set on using a hook the way around it is to put the hook somewhere outside the repo.  In a corporate setting you can do that in the `/etc/mercurial/hgrc` file on all systems, which if you have a decent IT setup they can do centrally.  Since it sounds like you're sure there will be a /home/configs user dir it sounds like you might be talking about all the clones being on a single machine, which case this is a fine option for you.  However, in an more decentralized environment you're back to having each person manually install the hook you want in their own `~/.hgrc`, and at that point you might as well just have them do the copy themselves.

**One idea worth considering** is checking if whatever is interpreting your `config.ini` file has an `include`-like directive?  Then you could have the cloned-down `config.ini` looks like:

```
... some stuff
%include /home/configs/config.ini
... more stuff
```

In which case no copy is necessary at all.  Mercurial, for example, does have an include directive which works just like that: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#syntax

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to define a [hook like changegroup](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec:hook:changegroup), in which you perform the copy right after the clone.
Only problem: that hook won't run with hard-linked paths, as reported in [issue 1602](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1602).

Comment: But this won't run after a clone, when by definition you have a *new repository*, without any hooks at all set up.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to hardlink the file, so that each time you run `hg update` in `/home/me/repo1` the file in `/home/configs` is updated as well:

```
rm /home/configs/config.ini
ln /home/me/repo1/config.ini /home/configs/config.ini
```

Note that you don't have to remove a clone and reclone to update your working copy. Just use `hg pull` and `hg update`.